# Eclipse and Tomcat 7

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

So I have an application where users can upload their documents. The problem is every time I redeploy the application (using Eclipse) this folder gets overwritten by the contents from the workspace.

How do I tell Eclipse to ignore certain folders on deployment?

Comment: where you are placing those folder ???

Comment: WEB-CONTENT/<my attachment Folder>

Answer (score 1):

**Don't put data/content inside your application**. Modify your logic to write documents to a path out of the application. like as :

```
   Application Path : C:\App\app.war

   Directory path : C:\App\documents
```

Comment: But then the application is distributed all over the place! I want to be able to just copy one folder and deploy to production.

Comment: If application is distributed then the reason to have data separate is even more stronger. See, a web app which has DB as well; DB is never part of your application. So use config files to control the path of your content.